# I want to get selected payment method on Billing tab of magento

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I have changed the checkout process order tabs in following manner-

1. Payment Method
2. Billing
3. Shipping
4. Review
5. Confirm Order

Now I want to get the selected Payment method on Shipping Tab. 
Actually I want make the back link on shipping Tab dynamic depends on selected Payment Method hence want to get the selected payment method on shipping tab so that I can write some code on back button.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.
-Pravin

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because payment method based on billing address.